# Input Text Design Issue for a search Box

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, xss

I am doing Java Web Application it has one search box.

```
  <input type="text" id="twotabsearchtextbox" title="Search For"
    value="${requestScope['searchKey']}" name="searchKey"
    autocomplete="off" class="tftextinput" data-nav-tabindex="10"
    tabindex="1"/>
```

if i search something regular it works fine. But if i search for

```
`<div id="test"> </div>`
```

something like html content it will searches fine but my design will break completely. Why it happens?
wen i search apple it comes in value section , like that if search for html content its coming in the value section.
How do i avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(you-search-value);`

Comment: is it possible to give at  value="${requestScope['searchKey']}" ??

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the code snippet ${requestScope['searchKey']}

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>
 <%
    String searchkey ="";
    if (request.getParameter("searchKey")!=null) {
        searchkey=request.getParameter("searchKey");
        searchkey=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(searchkey);      
    }
  %>
```

and changed the existing code according like

```
<input type="text" id="twotabsearchtextbox" title="Search For"
    value="${requestScope['searchKey']}" name="searchKey"
    autocomplete="off" class="tftextinput" data-nav-tabindex="10"
    tabindex="1"/>
```

Now the problem fixed for me